# Why in java we can't take user input int and string by one scanner object ?

Tags: java

I called a scanned object, using same object I am trying to take from user a int and a string.

```
Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
//for a int 
int first_value  = scan.nextInt();
System.out.println(first_value); 
//for a string
String  first_name = scan.nextLine();
System.out.println(first_name);
```

Here console not waiting for string but If I use another object then it's working fine.

```
 Scanner insert = new Scanner(System.in);
 String name = insert.nextLine();
```

Is it possible to get int and string using same Scanner object ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is because after reading int there left a `new line` character which was consumed by your `scan.nextLine` and it did not wait for your next input. You need to consume it before reading a String.

```
Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
//for a int 
int first_value  = scan.nextInt();
scan.nextLine();
System.out.println(first_value); 
//for a string
String  first_name = scan.nextLine();
System.out.println(first_name)
```

Comment: Because the new line character is buffered in `Scanner` not in `System.in`so if you try reading it with a different scanner it will wait for your input.

Answer (score 0):

Use `System.out.println("Enter Your Age");` and `System.out.println("Enter Your Name");` just before taking input from user by `Scanner` Object.

```
System.out.println("Enter your first name:");
String first_name = scan.nextLine();

System.out.println("Enter your age:");
int age = Integer.parseInt(scan.nextLine());
```

> Now it enables you to hold the screen For entering you Input to the Program.